# Using pyyaml, how can I override an anchor in a YAML config and have the updated anchor be persisted throughout?

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml, yaml-anchors

Here's an example of the file `config.yml`:

```
key_setting: &key_setting
  True

main_params:
  param_A:
    param_A_1: 1
    param_A_2: 2
    param_A_setting: *key_setting
  param_B:
    param_B_1: 3
    param_B_2: 4
    param_B_setting: *key_setting
```

If I run `yaml.load(open('config.yml').read())`, `param_A_setting` and `param_B_setting` would both be `True`, which was set by `key_setting`.

Suppose I want to override `key_setting` to `False` and have that persist across `param_A_setting` and `param_B_setting`.  How can I do that by overriding only `key_setting` without needing to manually override `param_A_setting` and `param_B_setting`?

Comment: I tried to play with yaml library in python and I got this output `{'key_setting': {'value': False}, 'main_params': {'param_A': {'param_A_1': 1, 'param_A_2': 2, 'param_A_setting': {'value': False}}, 'param_B': {'param_B_1': 3, 'param_B_2': 4, 'param_B_setting': {'value': False}}}}`.

Comment: How did you do this?

Answer (score 0):

We should update the `key_setting` anchor directly, which would in turn affect both `param_A_setting` and `param_B_setting`, so first the `config.yml` file would need a slight modification

```
key_setting: &key_setting
  value: True

main_params:
  param_A:
    param_A_1: 1
    param_A_2: 2
    param_A_setting: *key_setting
  param_B:
    param_B_1: 3
    param_B_2: 4
    param_B_setting: *key_setting
```

then we can update the `value` key under `key_setting` to `False`

```
import yaml

data = yaml.safe_load(open('config.yml').read())

# Override key_setting
data['key_setting']['value'] = False

# Now, param_A_setting and param_B_setting are both False
print(data)
```

**Output**

```
{'key_setting': {'value': False}, 'main_params': {'param_A': {'param_A_1': 1, 'param_A_2': 2, 'param_A_setting': {'value': False}}, 'param_B': {'param_B_1': 3, 'param_B_2': 4, 'param_B_setting': {'value': False}}}}
```